# The same thing again - Lenovo.Modern.ImController.PluginHost.Device.exe

Tags: services, plugins, hosts, controller

I have the same problem again and again with "Lenovo.Modern.ImController.PluginHost.Device.exe"
that stopped working (then it was "companionapp.exe", now it's "pluginhost.exe"). I've read many articles but they only say 2 things: Either delete SIF completely (which is not a good idea) or terminate process/delete the ".exe" that causes the problem, but if you do it manually may cause other problems too! The thing is that, a few days ago I posted another question about the same thing. I deleted SIF and downloaded the latest version, but now the problem showed up again...What can I do?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you contacted Lenovo support directly?

Comment: Lenovo Vantage, Lenovo Companion, Modern IM Controller and System Interface Foundation all play together. I read your prior post also. It may be best at this point to do a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link. Use the option to download, and download to a USB Key.  Run Setup.exe from the USB Key and when the option comes up, pick the option to Keep Everything.

Comment: No I didn't contact directly with them...But if the problem persists I'll do a Windows Repair.
Thank you guys!

Comment: Is it MediaCreationTool20H2, and do that with the help of a USB stick? And also, is it the same if I go to Settings and do a Windows Recovery from there (and keep my files)?

Comment: Media Creation Link can reinstall Windows and Keep Data and Apps. This is a choice you have when running it:  Keep Everything, Keep Data only, Keep Nothing. It will attempt to update to the newest version of production Windows.  It is much better to use than Windows Recovery which normally just keeps Data if it can. I prefer Repair Install if it works.

Comment: So...If I use this technique (Reinstalling Windows 10) do I have to pay for a new activation key to activate Windows 10 (Windows 10 Pro in my case) ?